# NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-data, slf4j

При включении аннотации `@EnableJpaRepositories` получаю такую ошибку:

```
Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder
```

Не могу разобраться в чем дело, spring-data-jpa добавляет slf4j определенной версии, пробовал разные версии slf4j ставить, но появлялись другие, разного рода, ошибки.

Вот мои зависимости (я так понимаю проблема может быть связана только с ними):

```
 <properties>
    <spring.mvc>5.0.0.RELEASE</spring.mvc>
    <javax.servlet>4.0.1</javax.servlet>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <spring.security>5.0.0.RELEASE</spring.security>
    <hibarnate.version>5.0.0.Final</hibarnate.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.mvc}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.mvc}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.servlet}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibarnate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>webapp</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь обсуждалась подобная проблема, посмотрите список зависимостей: [enablejparepositories-dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35680749/enablejparepositories-dependency)

Еще пример с набором зависимостей по вашему контексту: [SpringMVC4 + Spring Data JPA + SpringSecurity configuration using JavaConfig](http://www.codingpedia.org/sivalabs/springmvc4-spring-data-jpa-springsecurity-configuration-using-javaconfig/)

Также надо помнить, что библиотеки являются зависимыми по версиям друг от друга. Соответственно версионность надо контролировать комплексно в связанных между собой библиотеках.

Добавьте:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но теперь получаю: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.PersistenceContext.synchronization(), тоже в зависимостях проблема?

Comment: Сложно без исходников проекта и полного текста Exception ответить. Попробуйте набор dependencies из примера в статье. Там, правда, пример под spring 4. Но я думаю, сейчас важнее скомпилировать и запуститься, а потом уже бантики.

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы подключить slf4j требуемой версии вы должны добавить в pom.xml

```
<properties>    
  <slf4jVersion>1.6.1</slf4jVersion>    
</properties>

<dependency>    
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>    
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>   
  <version>${slf4jVersion}</version>    
</dependency>
```

а потом использовать один из байндингов например к log4j

```
<!--Binding for log4j version 1.2.x You also need to place log4j.jar on your class path. -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <version>${slf4jVersion}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.16</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```